# Code is fine(?), but app is running slow on Android (service+ intents)

Tags: java, android, performance

So I've got 3 java files :

1. ServiceActivity - main activity where everything starts ( static int i   is defined earlier in this file)
2. Elserwis - it is the service (it has a timer where I've passed the variable i -> it will be the hour since when the timer must turn on)
3. Sekundo - the intent where user puts the hour => >variable i<

Here is the fragment of code from main activity -> ServiceActivity:

```
private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sekundo.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1337);
    }         
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    /* Place out code to react on Activity-Result here. */
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1337){
        i=data.getIntExtra("result",5);
        Toast tost = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ELO"+data.getIntExtra("result",0)+data.getIntExtra("result1",0), 1000);
        tost.show();
        startService(new Intent(SerwisActivity.this,Elserwis.class));  
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the end, where startService lays (as a subfunction of onActivityResult)

If you need any other fragment of code I can paste it here, but the question is:
My app is running very slowly at the beginning when the timer starts, and the `Toast` shows for over 1 minute. Anyone know why?

## EDIT:

```
     public class Elserwis extends Service {
 
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
 
  okresowePowiadomienie();
 
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service LAUNCHED!", 1000).show();
  

 }

 
 Date data33 = new Date(111,11,SerwisActivity.i,2,25);
 int d = data33.getDate();
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 public void okresowePowiadomienie(){
     
 
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
      
  public void run() {
       
       
     
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"OKRes",System.currentTimeMillis());
     
    Intent notIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SerwisActivity.class);  
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, 0);
     
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),"Powiadomienie x:","Kliknij aby d:usunac ;)t:"+d,contentIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
     
    notificationManager.notify(1335, notification);
  // }  };
  }};
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask ,data33 , 120000); }
 

@Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     
  super.onDestroy();
  timer.cancel();
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service dead!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

thats just alpha version of my code but final will be similar ( now it only passes information about the day to my service -> in final version it should pass hour and minute)

The "Service LAUNCHED!" toast stays on for ages, it crashes most of the time on AVD, on my real smartphone it just takes long but still it should work smoothly...

---

Basically the problem started when i moved startService from onClick() function  TO the onActivityResult. It needs to stay there because service uses the int i (user types types int i in the new intent) to set the data for my timer(timer is in the Elserwis). I've updated my first post with the service code so u can get what i mean

Comment: so there is no problem if you remove `startService`? Surely `startService` shouldn't block? What's in the `onStartCommand`?

Comment: I've edited first post so u can see more of my code maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm GUESSING that `startService` itself is not causing any blocking.
I'm GUESSING that you have code in `startService` that takes awhile to complete and causes your application UI to lock up.

If this is the case, then what you would need to do is create a new thread inside your service before running the code that causes the delay.

You need to keep any long-running blocks of code in a separate thread to not block the UI. I would be interested in the code that is in `Elserwis.class` because that would help identify where the problem actually lies. Or if you look at your code and figure it out based on what I said, then you need not post any more code.

Comment: Basically the problem started when i moved startService from onClick() function <which ive posted before> TO the onActivityResult.  It needs to stay there because service uses the int i (user types types int i in the new intent) to set the data for my timer(timer is in the Elserwis). I've updated my first post with the service code so u can get what i mean.